# Nifi - Process the files based on count or time elapsed?

Tags: apache-nifi

I have a following flow,
ListFile ---> FetchFile ---> ? ExecuteScript (maybe) ---> Notify

Basically, I want to go to Notify, if

- Total flowfiles (from fetch files) is say 200; ***OR***
- Time elapsed (from last signal) is say 3 hours.

I think the 1st condition is easy to achieve. I can have a groovy script which can read number of flowfiles, if 200 go to SUCCESS or else ROLLBACK the session.

But I want to know how to also check the time elapsed for n (number can be less than 200) flowfiles in queue is more than 3 hours or so?

**Update**
Here is the problem: We have a batch processing (~200 files and can increase based on business in future) currently. We have a NiFi pipeline, i.e. List, Fetch, Basic validation on checksum, etc and process (call the SQL) which is working fine.
As per the business, throughout the day we can have the correction to data so that we can get all or some of the files to "re-process". That is also fine and working.

Now, as per new requirements, we need to build the process after this "batch" is completed. So in the best case, I can have the MergeContent processor with max bin of n and give the signal or notify to my new processor.
However, as explained above, throughout that day we can get few or all files processed again. So now my "n" may not match the new "number" of files re-processed. Hence, even in this case if we have elapsed say 3 hours, then irrespective of "n" not equal to new number of files reprocessed, I should notify the new process to run again.
Hence, I am looking for n files OR m hours elapsed check.

Answer (score 1):

I think this may be an example of an [*XY problem*](https://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=542341) -- you're trying to solve a problem and believe that counting the number of files fetched or time elapsed will help, but this pattern is usually discouraged in Apache NiFi and there are other solutions to the original problem. I would encourage you to describe more fully the higher level problem you are trying to solve to see if there is a better solution.

I will answer the question though (none of these are ideal solutions).

- You can use a `MergeContent` processor with a minimum bin count of 200
- You can use an `ExecuteScript` processor as you noted
- You can write a value (the current timestamp) to a `DistributedCacheMapServer` when the `Notify` processor executes, and check that value with a `FetchDistributedCacheMap` processor against the current timestamp and use a simple Expression Language statement to compare the timestamp values

I think you may also want to read some examples of `Wait`/`Notify` logic, because creating thresholds like "200 incoming flowfiles || 3 hours elapsed time" is what the `Wait` processor does.

- ["How to wait for all fragments to be processed, then do something?" by Koji Kawamura](http://ijokarumawak.github.io/nifi/2017/02/02/nifi-notify-batch/)
- ["NiFi workflow monitoring – Wait/Notify pattern with split and merge" by Pierre Villard](https://pierrevillard.com/2018/06/27/nifi-workflow-monitoring-wait-notify-pattern-with-split-and-merge/)
- ["Simple NiFi Wait/Notify Example" answer by Abdelkrim Hadjidj](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/186215/simple-nifi-160-waitnotify-example.html)

Comment: Hi Andy, thanks for getting back. I have edited by question with some more details about current process and new requirements.
Wait and Notify does make sense, I will explore more about it to see how to fit "n files || m minutes" check there. Thanks.